# Why does Visual Studio 2012 list browser multiple times in Default Browser Switcher?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

For some reason, VS2012 lists Google Chrome several times in the Default Browser Switcher. I have tried removing Chrome and uninstalling again, searched everywhere, but have found no solution to the problem. Going through the "Browse With" dialog and removing the options on there doesn't work.

[image: Default Browser Switcher]

Any ideas?

Comment: This normally comes from a file, C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\browsers.xml.  Have a look at it.  If you see duplicate entries then make a backup copy and delete them.

Comment: Looking into that file, Google Chrome is only listed once.

Comment: Quacks like a bug, post a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Posted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804391/

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many users are on your system?

Comment: It's my company provided laptop, so I am the sole user on it.

Comment: Still happens in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019. It makes me nuts.